# How to convert for loop to do-while loop?

Tags: java, do-while

This is a question from the book *Introduction to Java* by Y Daniel Liang:

> Convert for  loop statement to a while loop and do-while loop?
>
> ```
> int sum = 0; 
> for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) 
>     sum = sum + i;
> ```

I am pretty confused on how to convert it to a do-while loop. What am I supposed to do? Please see my code below.

```
public class Convert_forLoop_toWhileLoop {
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int sum = 0;
       int i = 0;
       do {
           sum = sum + i;
           System.out.println(sum);
           i++;
       } while(i <= 7); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You did just fine

Comment: I'm with @BinyaminSharet here--that looks 100% correct to me.

Comment: That is perfect and no problem with the above code.

Comment: Yeah... I answered, but I see now that it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how scrupulous you wanna be, a "more" equivalent `do`-`while`-loop of your `for`-loop example would be:

```
int sum1(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int sum2(int n) {
    int sum = 0; 
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (i <= n) {
            do {
                sum = sum + i;
                i++;
            } while (i <= n);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note I wrapped your example in `sum1` (passing `sum1(7)` is equivalent to your case).

For those who really want to split hairs -- note Java doesn't necessarily compile the 2 functions above into the same bytecode (at least when I tested it, to my surprise). 2 extra bytecode instructions for `sum2` (20 vs. 22). Just something interesting I noticed.

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

do {
   sum += i;
   i++;
} while (i <= 7);

System.out.println("The sum of 0 thru " +i + " is:" + sum);
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and the code displayed in the question ?

Comment: Not much.  I didn't proof his before answering, but you'll note from my comment above that I saw his solution was fine after the fact.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who tried to solve my small problem. Many many thanks again. Your answers really helped

Answer (score -2):

Your answer doesnt support the case where i initial value is >= number of loops.

you need to first check the condition.

```
while (i <= 7) {
    sum+=i;
   // at the last statement increase i
   i++
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Given that his code sets `i = 0` in the declaration, and sets number of loops to 7, I'm pretty sure you won't run into a problem where `0 >= 7`.

Comment: today you have 7 hard coded, tomorrow you have a variable of unknown value.
if you can't switch 7 with a variable, than its not a good practice.

Comment: He asked for a do/while loop. Not that it's feasible in general.